# search program in txt file java code

Tags: java

I wanna develop java program with following task.

use enter file name and also enter product code. and as result its show all products details

for example.

file data is MLK#milk#expired date 15 may 2016

output will be

this product name is milk with MLK code and will expired in 15 may 2016.

help me thanks...

my code is...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class search 
{

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException 
    {


        String word = ""; int val = 0;
        while(!word.matches("quit"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched for");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            word = input.next();
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("stationMaster.txt"));

            while(file.hasNextLine())           
            {
                String line = file.nextLine();
                if(line.indexOf(word) != -1)
                {
                    while(file.hasNextLine())
                    {       

                        String data=file.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(data);
                    }


                    //System.out.println("");
                    val = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    val = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(val == 0)
            {
            System.out.println("Station does not exist");
            break;
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tokens[] = null;
        String code, product, date;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                tokens = line.split("#");
                code = tokens[0];
                product = tokens[1];
                date = tokens[2];

                System.out.println("this product name is " + product
                        + " with " + code
                        + " code and will expired in"
                        + date.substring(12));
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found exception.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO Eception occered.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How does e.getMessage(); do anything for this person other than not compile?

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class search 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException 
    {
        String word = ""; int val = 0;
        while(!word.matches("quit"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the word to be searched for");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            word = input.next();
            Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("stationMaster.txt"));

            while(file.hasNextLine())           
            {
                String line = file.nextLine();

                //split the string on # character so that you get code, product name and expiration date separately.

                String arr[] = line.split("#");

                //check whether the string contains the required string or not

                try{
                    if(arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase(word) || arr[1].equalsIgnoreCase(word)){                                   
                        //line break
                        System.out.println();

                        //split the format 'expiration date 15 may 2016' so that we can use date separately without the heading of 'expiration date'
                        String dateStrings[] = arr[2].split(" ");

                        System.out.print("this product name is " + arr[1] + " with " + arr[0] + " code and will expire on ");
                        System.out.println(dateStrings[2] + " " + dateStrings[3] + " " + dateStrings[4]);
                        val = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        val = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException indexEx){
                    val = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if(val == 0){
                System.out.println("Station does not exist");
                break;
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

The above code will search the string that will be read from the file if it contains the word to search or not. It can be product code or product name

Comment: Where is your try/catch to snag exceptions?

Comment: cant get date and check it again

Comment: I have written the code according to the format you gave. What is the issue?

Comment: no error. but when i run the program i cant get dates. i get only name and code

Comment: i cant used array and try catch block .. so without using this i have to done this program

Comment: Please post the string with which you are checking the program with

Comment: program shouldn't used array and try catch block... and also display give output as i posted in my question. please hwlp me thanks

Comment: Can u please post the file you are using to get the data ? I will then edit the program according to your requirement